# Getting DataGridView rows shifting code working?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can someone help me fix this piece of code I found?
It's suppose to shift a whole row up on a winform datagridview.

It works like it's supposed to except for the fact that the old row position stays selected when there is only 1 selected item shifted.

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows = dataGridView.SelectedRows;
dataGridView.ClearSelection();  //this does not work.
for (int i = 0; i <= selectedRows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    int selRowIndex = selectedRows[i].Index;
    if (selRowIndex > 0)
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Remove(selectedRows[i]);
        dataGridView.Rows.Insert(selRowIndex - 1, selectedRows[i]);
        dataGridView.Rows[selRowIndex - 1].Selected = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: if the row is not selected this shouldn't work as `selectedRows.Count` is 0 and doesn't even get into the `for`

Comment: The code originally had no ClearSelection() call. I added it to try to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a fan of what that code you found was trying to do.  Try moving selected rows up this way:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i) {
  if(dataGridView.Rows[i].Selected) {
    var prevRow = dataGridView.Rows[i - 1];
    dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i - 1);
    dataGridView.Rows.Insert(i, prevRow);          
  }
}
```

Do not call ClearSelection().

To move the selected rows down, try it this way:

```
for (int i = dataGridView.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Selected) {
    var prevRow = dataGridView.Rows[i + 1];
    if (!prevRow.IsNewRow) {
      dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i + 1);
      dataGridView.Rows.Insert(i, prevRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it was on msdn, why?

Comment: one more thing. I can seems to get the opposite effect using this code, where the items shifts down. I just assumed I just had to change all the 'i-1' to 'i+1'

Comment: @Shadowblitz16 I've noticed you haven't accepted any answers.  It's the check mark next to the post.